# Ubuntu 22.04 RDP client/host resolution mismatch

Tags: vnc, rdp, remmina, 4k-monitor

Getting RDP to work on Ubuntu 22.04 is fairly straightforward. But on my client machine I have a 4k monitor whereas on the host I have a 1440p monitor. Using Remmina I can't find a way to connect using the client resolution (4k).

Since the screen is mirrored from the host screen to the RDP connection it gives me the impression I cannot do that with the default RDP support in 22.04? I tried both RDP and VNC and both had the same behaviour.

If so, what are my options?

Comment: I've sort of re-asked this question on StackExchange as I hadn't seen this. It is so frustrating as I need a bigger screen in which to work on my microsoft remote desktop login. :grrrr

Answer (score 0):

You could try either of the following setups. I have tried both, they each provide a higher resolution UI experience, but they also both have some limitations.

Setup 1 - use xrdp as the host service on the server, launched from a command line rather than a graphical interface.

1. (one time) modify your server startup configuration to boot to multi-user.target, which boots to a terminal command line rather than to the graphical user interface
2. (one time) if it is not already installed on your server, install xrdp
3. ssh into the server from the client
4. start xrdp on the server as a service using the command: sudo systemctl start xrdp
5. remote into the server from a remote desktop client configured for full screen on your box with the high resolution monitor

The UI that's displayed in this case is gnome desktop, although it's not configured exactly the same as the desktop which comes up in a graphical session directly on the server.

This works well on the client for me, so long as I restrict direct access on the server box to a terminal session. However, if I've connected to the server via remote desktop, and then also try to start the graphical UI directly on the server, the monitor attached to the server displays only a black screen. (The client session continues to function.)

---

Setup 2 - use x2go with mate desktop

1. (one time) install x2go-server and mate desktop on the server. The specific packages to install are x2goserver, x2goserver-xsession, and ubuntu-mate-desktop.
2. (one time) install x2go client on the client box with the high res monitor
3. (one time) in x2goclient, configure a connection from the client to the server, choose mate for the desktop environment, and full screen
4. connect to the server through the x2go client

The mate desktop is simpler than the default gnome desktop, but I find it fully functional for my purposes. One idiosyncracy I have observed in x2go is that neither firefox nor chromium works properly if started graphically in an x2go client session. A workaround for this is to open a terminal window in the x2go client session on the server,set the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS environment variable manually using this command: export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus, and then launch either firefox or chromium from the terminal command line. In my experience, this issue is limited to these two browsers for whatever reason. Other graphical programs that I've tested do not have a similar issue.